# Table drawing software

Tags: 16.04

Hi I've got a big table (11x24) to do and it's becoming problematic with LibreOfficeWriter, does anyone know some software or online apps for doing that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **LibreOffice** package there is special program for that purpose. Its name is [**Calc**](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/).